# Get "Sort by" method in catalog page

Tags: magento2, catalog, sort-by-options

How can i get "Sort By" method in this page, `$productListToolbar` doesnt include sort by position method.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar');
$order = $productList->getCurrentOrder();
```